# WPF C# Show images in stack panel

Tags: wpf, image, view, stackpanel

I am actually solving the issue with stack panel and images I would like to show in it.

What my approach was:
Because of just about 50 pictures to be shown , I just get ti image , make a thumbnail from it , and place that one by one to the stackpanel on left side of my program. (As bitmap)
User is able to click on image and do the action with a image.
Required amount was about 50 images.

New state:
New state is that the required amount of images is about 500 so 10 times more.
The problem is even my thumbnail is too small when I am adding it like :

foreach image in list do :

- create thumbnail
- add on click or and on touch event to that thumbnail
- add that thumbnail to the stack panel

I saw somewhere was used a picture box , not sure if that will help me.

I am thinking about creating lists of pictures links (50  in every ) and put for instance first in a scroll bar and when scrollbar reaches the bottom, load next and when the top reaches load previous list.

The problem is I am reaching with ~ 175 images the maximum of process memory.
I am waiting for garbage collector to do its job after every cycle.

Maybe my approach is not good or should be different so this is why I am asking which approach use in order to solve this problem you suggest.

The source of the photos is simply folder of thumbnails of size 150x150 .

The images are added one by one in certain period of time ( one foto every one second or so )

Thank you

Comment: Use a ListBox with an Image element in the ItemTemplate. ListBox uses a VirtualizingStackPanel by default, i.e. it only loads those images that are currently visible in its ScrollViewer. Bind the ItemsSource property to a collection of path strings, and create the thumbnails by a Binding Converter on the Source Binding of the Image element.

Comment: @Clemens
I do not know why , but this solution-for instance solution provided by EldHasp below causing me performance issues  - delay - response of scrolling is quite bad. 
To make sure , I just copied and pasted the code . As far as I remember I faced that issue in past . 
So that is why I am using ScrollViewer with BitmapImages (Images) for WPF but need to be cached. Performance is ++ but process memory problems are now present ( I am not sure if something was changed a little bit because would say I tested it on much more images ) - I was aware of process max size

Answer (score 0):

An example of implementation.

1. Create a collection of images sources.
   The collection can contain a string or an Url with a path to the image.
   In this case, the image will be created only when it is shown in the Window.
   You can also set an instance of ImageSource (or rather classes derived from it).
   In this case, the image will be immediately loaded into memory.
   Also set the property for specifying the selected image.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace ImagesViewer
{
    public class ImagesViewerViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<object> ImagesSource { get; }
            = new ObservableCollection<object>()
            {
                "https://miro.medium.com/max/2400/0*UEtwA2ask7vQYW06.png",
                new Uri("https://149351115.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/stackoverflow-prosus-blue-orange.png"),
                new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://amazinghiring.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/jpddcgb89ow.jpg"))
            };

        public object SelectedImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2. Bind the ListBox source to the created collection.
   In the Element Template, specify the Image with the binding to the element and the thumbnail sizes you need.
   Assign the selected item to the property for the selected image.
   The ListBox has a VirtualizingStackPanel built in by default, so you don't need to take any additional steps to limit using memory.
   In the viewing region, set the Image with a binding to the property for the selected image.

```
<Window x:Class="ImagesViewer.ImagesViewerWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImagesViewer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ImagesViewerWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
            <local:ImagesViewerViewModel/>
        </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesSource}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Margin="5"
                           Width="100" Height="100"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Image Grid.Column="1"
               Source="{Binding SelectedImage}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> Ok but scoriling of list of 170 150x150 causing the slowinest of the program as I already mentioned . I did the test already. Can you confirm or refute that please ?

**Тестирование.**

1. More than 1200 images in JPG and PNG formats are pre-recorded in the folder "C:\150x150".
2. The ViewModel gets a list of files in this folder and creates a string array with their paths.
   The time for this operation is also recorded.

```
    public class ImagesViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> ImagesPaths { get; }
        public long ExecutionTimeGetPaths {get;}
        public ImagesViewModel()
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            ImagesPaths = Directory.GetFiles("C:/150x150")
                .Where(path => path.EndsWith(".jpg") || path.EndsWith(".png"))
                .ToArray();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            ExecutionTimeGetPaths = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
```

3. In View in the upper right corner displays the time taken to get the paths of all files.
   On the left side is a ListBox showing images in size 150x150 for all files.

```
<Window x:Class="Eee.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Eee"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ImagesViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ExecutionTimeGetPaths}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   FontSize="30" Margin="10"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesPaths}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}"
                           Width="150" Height="150"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

4. Results: the time of obtaining the paths is 12-14 ms, the images are displayed instantly.
   **There are NO LAGS AT ALL when scrolling**.
5. The same was verified for image files of arbitrary format from 128x128 to 4200x2800.
   **The result is the same.**

Comment: Besides that images will not be "immediately loaded into memory" when you use only the BitmapImage constructor, an ObservableCollection of BitmapImages will still not scale well.

Comment: Your post does also not address the "create thumbnail" part. There should be a Binding Converter that creates a thumbnail BitmapImage by setting its DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight property.

Comment: You are absolutely right.
I did not increase the example code too much, because the implementation used by TC is unknown.
Where does it get the image from?
Maybe this is an array of bytes from the database?
Maybe some other source, not typical for WPF.
Therefore, I did not add details that for TC may be superfluous.
If TC supplements its question with implementation details, I will modify the code as per your recommendations.

Comment: Take all that as an indication that there should not be an answer at all. The question needs to be more focused on a specific problem, and should hence be edited or closed.

Comment: I think the image source does not matter but I added that.

Comment: If I understood correctly, there is a path to the folder containing the thumbnails.
It is necessary to show ALL FILES of this folder via Image 150x150 list.
Do you create these thumbnails yourself and you just need to periodically check this folder?
How do you display the selected image?
Or is it not important?
When the user clicks, the file corresponding to the thumbnail will be selected, is that enough for further implementation of your logic?

Comment: @EldHasp
Hallo , thanks for answering and sorry for not explaining that properly, from my point of view seems clear but maybe is not .  Yes you are right . 
I create these thumbnails and put it directly to folder e.g.  
_italic_ C:/appdata _italic_

What I did: I changed it to proposed by you. 
For a update, and firing the onpropertychanged I just make a temporary observable collection of objects (Images URIs) and  I put that - join , my local observable collection to ImagesSource which is also the same type ( Observable collection of objects URIs)

Comment: @EldHasp sorry for double comment my comment was too long : 
It works quite well but scrolling causing serious performance issues ...

edit: I was solving that issue I do not know a year ago and for performance was best BitmapImage and place that bitmap image into scroll viewer , of course that the bitmap image must have the cache set to be still available and that causing the process memory problems.  It is not happy solution but with that I avoided performance issues , but something has changed and got process memory issues

Comment: As I understand it, loading directly while browsing is not satisfactory due to problems during scrolling.
VirtualizingStackPanel, as far as I remember, preloads only one invisible element.
If you actively scroll, then loading will occur after showing the image area in the visible area.
Is it really important for a 150x150 miniature?
I am surprised.
You can check this variant.
Create ObservableCollection with BitmapIage.
Load all your miniatures into this collection and freeze each image.
Write down how many miniatures there are, how much time and memory it took.

Comment: @EldHasp  Thank you for discussion and willingness to help . 
To make it much more clearer ( I can add that to the problem description as well ) there is a preview area - like some bar on left side where x of n images are listed (e.g.) depends on resolution it is full screen app , so for instance there are 5 thumnails visible) and user can scroll in this item from list of images and select the thumbnail  ....  if he select the thumbnail , image opens in a center grid as a selected and user can do actions above it .

Comment: @EldHasp And actual problem is, that I have observable collection of images , but I need to substitute StackPanel.Children.Add () which I have in my original solution... .
Lets try and do the easy example. 
Create stackpanel in  WPF window where height is 700 and width is e.g. 300, 
As easiest solution create bitmapimage from image source located in directory 
on each image create preview mouse right button down event which shows message box "you clicked" 
than , add this to the stackpanel using MyStackPanel.Children.Add(Image)
For image use:

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.Image myImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
                        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(str))
                        {
                            var bmp = new BitmapImage();
                            bmp.BeginInit();
                            bmp.StreamSource = stream;

                            bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                            bmp.EndInit();
                            myImage.Source = bmp;
                        }

Continuesly add e.g. one picture per second to the folder

Comment: You don't have to create UI elements directly and add to the StackPanel.
This will really load the memory a lot.
Take a look at my example code.
I am filling with images via ListBox.
LixtBox uses VirtualizingStackPanel by default, not StackPanel.
VirtualizingStackPanel will itself create UI elements (Image from Uri or string) for the visible area only.
Therefore, no memory load, even a huge collection of Uri or string of thousands of elements, does not create.
And on my computer, 150x150 images are created almost instantly.

Comment: @EldHasp Ok but scoriling of list of 170 150x150 causing the slowinest of the program as I already mentioned . I did the test already. Can you confirm or refute that please ? Because what I am trying to say is that this is not a solution and would like to hear if the same happens for instance to you. Would be realy nice . Parameters are 170 thumnails in Observable collection of uri , height of window approx 600px so 6 shown at time , scrollable causing problem with performance (scrolling not smooth)

Comment: I tested it on purpose.
Read the result in my answer.

Comment: @EldHasp - Tested today once again 

images count ~200 150x150, 
After 170th photo in listbox scrolled down application stopped to response. 
Also scrolling up and down was just slow for device with touchpad , user expects to can scroll through the list of images like in gallery in e.g. android but this is just list not the grid with 3x3 photos just 1xn list 

My fix to that is,to create list of image lists (50) and if I am at the end there is a button and user can click load more,application adds 50 photos from next list if exists and  removes 50 photos at the top of the list if exists

Comment: Perhaps for mobile devices there will be a different result.
I tested on Windows Desktop.
You should be sure to include this detail, as it is an important part of the problem.
How WPF works on other devices - I don't know.
And I can't say anything about this.

Comment: @EldHasp Maybe my English is too bed , sorry for that , but with "  like in gallery in e.g. android but" I meant that I would like the functionality like in Android Gallery where you can scroll through the list (to be precise grid(3xn) - but what I need is list (1xn not e.g. 3x3) and requirement was to be able to do that fast (I mean like swipe movement fast load and preview)  so the Virtualization solves problem with memory , but causing slowness during scrolling I would say in case of ~ 200 miniatures

Comment: @EldHasp - I cannot add the answer for this due to some magic reasons I do not understand yet , but the solution is use your approach but have multiple observable collections with URIs to switch between max of 20 images was OK for faster scrolling , OR what seems to me better, is to use ObservableCollection(OC) of OC[25]of Strings, and load e.g. 2 to be OK with 32bit process room , than add last and first Tile (or clickable button)  Show Less(top) or Show more(bottom) - like pagination and add GC explicit all after removal (before adding ) - I used Stackpanel as parameter to my viewmodel ....

Comment: For me, English is not native and I know it poorly.
Therefore, let's better deal with the problem itself.
I will clarify again. I tested on Windows 10 Desktop. Display images in one vertical column.
Does this test suit you, is it identical to the implementation you require?
Did you test my example in a separate Solution (to exclude the influence of other codes)?

Comment: You are writing about StackPanel again.
In your case, it cannot be used!
To pass the child elements to it, you have to load them.
And it completely breaks any virtualization.
You must use VirtualizingStackPanel.
Is the easiest way to do this through a ListBox, as I showed in my example.